# Photoshop script (JSX) - history snapshots count?

Tags: photoshop, history, snapshot, jsx

I'm new to Photoshop JSX scripting. Until now I did script a little "hello world" that saves a jpg image of the first history snapshot.

What I want is to know the number of history snapshots present in the active image but I can't find any good info or example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution (Thanks to c.pfaffenbichler):

```
xvar myDoc = app.activeDocument;
var theHist = myDoc.historyStates;
var theSnaps = new Array;
for (var m = 0; m < theHist.length; m++) {
var theState = theHist[m];
if (theState.snapshot == true) {theSnaps.push(theState)}
};
alert (theSnaps.length);
```

Nice. Isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate through `Document.HistoryStates` and test the boolean called `snapshot` for each one - it is `true` if the state is a snapshot.

Comment: I understand the concept but not how to script it. I'll try to find how to do that :)  Many thanks, Mark.